# regular functions over non-reduced curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that the regular functions over a connected compact complex manifold are constants. I wonder that if this is true for non-reduced compact complex space. More precise, Let $X$ be a complex compact manifold of dimension three and $I\subset \mathcal O_X$ an ideal such that the complex subspace $C$ defined by $I$ is of dimension one. Then, I want to know if we have
$$H^0(C,\mathcal O_X/I)=\mathbb C.$$
If not, how about we suppose that $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X)=H^1(C,\mathcal O_X/I)=0$?

Now what in my mind is an example as following. Let $X=\mathbb P^3$ and $C$ is the curve defined by $x_2^2=x_3=0$ where $[x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3]$ is the coordinate on $\mathbb P^3$. Then by adjunction formula, we can show that $H^1(C,\mathcal O_C)=1$, and by a explicit calculation, we can also show that $H^0(C,\mathcal O_C)=0$. In general, we consider the following short exact sequence,
$$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow \mathcal O_X\rightarrow \mathcal O_C\rightarrow 0.$$
Under the assumption $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X)=H^1(C,\mathcal O_C)=0$. Then $H^0(C,\mathcal O_C)=\mathbb C$ is equivalent to show that $H^1(X,I)=0$. But I do not know how to show this or how to construct a counterexample.

Thank you very much for your answer or any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a complete intersection curve like yours ($x_2^2=x_3=0$), then by Koszul resolution, you can easily show that $H^1(I)=0$. But, in general, there are non-reduced curves (connected) in 3-space which have $H^0(\mathcal{O}_C)\neq 0$.

Here is a standard construction. For definiteness, take a line $L$ in 3-space. Then $I_L/I_L^2=\mathcal{O}_L(-1)^2$ and so we can find a surjection to $\mathcal{O}_L(k)$ for any $k\geq -1$ from this rank two vector bundle. The push-out using $0\to I_L/I_L^2\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}/I_L^2\to \mathcal{O}_L\to 0$ gives a subscheme (sometimes called a ribbon) which will have $H^0=H^0(\mathcal{O}_L)\oplus H^0(\mathcal{O}_L(k))$ and thus if you take $k\geq 0$, you get such examples.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice example.